# Query data from other table in questionnaire model

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-design

I facing a super noob question and I need your help :)

FYI: I'm working with nodejs and mysql.

I have a database with products and they have tags/characteristics linked in a many to many relationship being:

```
products --> product_tags <-- tags
```

I also have a questionnaire table composed by questions and for those questions, some have options other are "text" response, but the thing is that one of those question is related with the tag table content...

```
questionnaire --> questionnaire_questions <-- questions --> options
                                                  |
                                                  |
                                                 tags
```

so my question is, how do I link that question/options to my tags table to help to select better products? is there a way to query that to include tags table options? I'm assuming I designed that table in the wrong way but I'm not sure how to tackle that.

If anyone can give me a hint I will be very grateful :)

Comment: are `tags` related to `products` table unique, if yes they are indirectly acting like a foreign key, else you need to give a direct reference to `questionnaire`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, but tags are related to products through product_tags table and tags are unique, but how should I show tags as an option for a given question? Not sure how to relate that :(